# Generic Interface Library: Could not load type from assembly

Tags: c#, generics, interface, mono

For experimental purposes, I am attempting to construct a binary search tree library from which a BST may be instantiated to hold either unique-only or redundant nodes (with a redundant node being one with a value equivalent to another in the tree).  For reusability, I have defined a single generic interface, ITree, and two sub-interfaces: IUnique and IRedundant.

Being the reason for my reply to [Explicit C# interface implementation of interfaces that inherit from other interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796188/explicit-c-interface-implementation-of-interfaces-that-inherit-from-other-interf), the library code may be demonstrated as follows [File Name: *itest.cs*]:

```
namespace MyNS {

    public interface INode<T,N>
        where N : INode<T,N> {

        N LChild { get; set; }
        N RChild { get; set; }

        T Value { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ITree<T,N,I>
        where N : INode<T,N> 
        where I : ITree<T,N,I> {

        void Add(N node);
    }

    public interface IUnique<T,N>
        : ITree<T,N,IUnique<T,N>>
        where N : INode<T,N> {
    }

    public interface IRedundant<T,N>
        : ITree<T,N,IRedundant<T,N>>
        where N : INode<T,N> {
    }

    public class Node<T>
        : INode<T,Node<T>> {

        public Node<T> LChild { get; set; }
        public Node<T> RChild { get; set; }

        public T Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tree<T>
        : IUnique<T,Node<T>>,
          IRedundant<T,Node<T>> {

        void ITree<T,Node<T>,IUnique<T,Node<T>>>.Add(Node<T> node) {
            /// Add node only if there is none with an equivalent value ///
        }

        void ITree<T,Node<T>,IRedundant<T,Node<T>>>.Add(Node<T> node) {
            /// Add node regardless of its redundancy ///
        }
    }
}
```

And an example main method [File Name: *main.cs*]:

```
public class ITest {
    public static void Main() {
        System.Console.WriteLine(typeof(MyNS.Tree<int>));
    }
}
```

Attempting to compile the library as a separate assembly from the main executable results in the following error:

```
$ mcs -out:itest.dll -t:library itest.cs
$ mcs -out:itest.exe main.cs -reference:itest
error CS0011: Could not load type 'MyNS.ITree`3[T,N,MyNS.IUnique`2[T,N]]' from assembly 'itest, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

However, compiling the two together works exactly as expected:

```
$ mcs -out:itest.exe main.cs itest.cs
$ mono itest.exe
MyNS.Tree`1[System.Int32]
```

To maintain modularity, how may I keep the library separate from my application logic?

*EDIT (Jan 11, 2010):* Yep, it was a bug with Mono 2.8.x, and has been fixed in version 2.10.

Comment: Works fine on .NET, I'd file a mono bug.

Comment: @Hans Passant, done.  https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=663727

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the mono compiler, so I can't tell you the right syntax, but I think the simpler answer is that your second library is not properly referencing the itest library. That they compile together properly is evidence that your code is correct.

I think you're 99% of the way there...just double-check your reference syntax.

Comment: Could it be a bug with the compiler?

Comment: I think it is a bug --- see my reply to @Hans Passant beneath my original post.  Thanks!